# Strange socket problem in python 3.2

Tags: python, sockets, version

I'm currently making a chat application in python.
It works like this:
1. The server is working
2. Clients enter their id and password
3. The login info are checked by the server
4. They are assigned a random number by the server
5. They can now send and recv message from and to the server

I'm having a problem at receiving the ID and the pass (please don't blame me for using global and exec)

```
def recv_server():
    global number
    global s     #the tcp socket
    exec("global sock"+number) #creating a specific sock for each connection
    exec("sock"+number+","+"sockname"+number+" = s.accept()")
    exec("logindata=sock"+number+".recv(65535)")
    logindata=logindata.decode()
    ...
```

Number being 1 the code would be:

```
global sock1
sock1, sockname1 = s.accept()
logindata=sock1.recv(65535)
```

I'm using python 3.2 on windows and when running the script, when login data would normaly have a value, now it's unassigned

```
File 'abc' line 23, in recv_server
logindata=logindata.decode()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'logindata' referenced before assigment
```

On my Linux computer(mint 11), sharing the file with dropbox and opening with python (2.7) doesn't give me any error

Now I'm asking if anybody knows what seems to be the cause of this problem?

Comment: Asking for help with a "please don't blame me for using global and exec" is like asking for help with a construction project and saying "please don't blame me for using mashed potatos instead of drywall".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch ouch ouch.

About the `global` stuff, I let it up to you to correct, but

```
def recv_server():
    global number
    global s     #the tcp socket
    global sockets
    sockets[number], sockname = s.accept()
    logindata = sockets[number].recv(65535)
    logindata = logindata.decode()
    ...
```

with a `sockets` defined maybe `sockets = {}` or so would be at least a try to code sensibly.

Then the `exec` is gone and only the `global` stays which is IMHO not good, but not as ugly as the other.

Your error stems from the compiler not recognizing the first assignment of `logindata` to happen because of the `exec` stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I used them and my projects is working again. Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

Try not using exec at all.

```
def recv_server():
    globals()["sock"+number], locals()["sockname"+number] = s.accept()
    logindata = locals()["sock"+number].recv(65535)
    logindata=logindata.decode()
```

I think there's a big misunderstanding of globals and locals at work
here.  First of all, if `number` and `s` are not assigned to in the
local (function) scope, then there's no need to declare them as
`global`s as they will only be read.  Secondly, why doess sockname#
need to be sockname# in the local scope.  It could just be sockname

Perhaps you're coming from a language w/o the same kind of scoping as Python?  If so your life would be much easier if you took the time to become familiar with the difference between local and global scope in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still don't understand where I have used logindata. EDIT: I have added full traceback to the error.

Comment: Oops, missed the exec, sorry.  Why are you using exec?  Updating answer.

Comment: @serban: In `logindata=logindata.decode()`, the first `logindata` is target of an assignment, and the second one is the "usage" which logically comes before the assignment. That is what the exception comes from.